# Pyautogui and PyDirectInput does not work on just one program

Tags: pyautogui

Im trying to automate a process on my job which is just creating and downloading pdf file like 1000 times but the problem is, i tried both library and both working normal on every test i made except one program that i need. Its not giving error, it looks like working but nothing happens.

I can still locate image on the screen but when i tried to send key or click to a button on program nothing happens. What can i do about this, is there any other way for this?

I tried both library with different programs but the only one i need is the only one that i get issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem today. There is no problem with any library, it was just because of the program that I need running as "Run as administrator" and because of that when I tried to run cmd administrator it's just working well. looks like both should be at the same level to get control over it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).