# Can not send keystrokes to one application with Python. Tried pyautogui, win32com and pydirectinput

Tags: python, win32com, pyautogui

I am writing an application for automation of various tasks for my work. I can send keystrokes to all applications except one. Mouse clicks also do not work.
The application is `EdgeCore View`. monitoring application for EC network equipment.

At the beginning I used `pyautogui`, then when it did not work on one application, I found on the internet that I should try `pydirectinput`. I know that this library is targeting mostly games, because they use `DX for I/O`. But I tried it anyway. It still did not work. At the end I tried `win32com` and it still does not work on one application. It works on all others so I will not add code. Code should work fine, if it works on other applications. Does anyone know what could be the problem? Or what else could I try?

p.s.

- The application is pretty old. In the logo it is written 2009-2016. I am using it on W10.
- I have to run the application in compatibility mode with W7

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was monitoring a simmilar thread ([Pyautogui and PyDirectInput does not work on just one program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838038/pyautogui-and-pydirectinput-does-not-work-on-just-one-program/74844636#74844636)), and the user solved his own problem. If your application is running as admin, your code also has to run as admin. If not, your code can not interact with application. I did not think of that.